# How exactly do I add a public ssh key to my DigitalOcean Droplet through Mac's Terminal?

Tags: php, linux, macos, ssh, command-line

Operating system: macOS Sierra

I changed my public and private ssh keys on Terminal many times. So when I "ssh" into the IP address given to me by my DigitalOcean Droplet (the IP address is `107.170.60.7`), I get the error of `Permission denied (publickey).` so I know it has to do with me changing the public/private key. So now I need to add that changed public key on my Terminal to my Droplet on DigitalOcean. There were two things suggested by the DigitalOcean community which I've tried:

1) A tutorial on how to change ssh keys - but this is for Windows users, not Mac. It suggests using "Search and Replace" and checking certain functionalities through that. But Macs don't have this so I can't use it, up to the "Search and Replace" part:
http://geektnt.com/how-to-add-ssh-key-to-existing-digitalocean-droplet.html

2) A user kept suggesting to someone else that the problem is resolved by visiting this page:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2
I read into it and it has everything to do with setting up a ssh key, which I already know, and NOTHING to do with how to ADD an ssh key to an existing Droplet.

I really just need to know how to add my changed ssh key to my Droplet. I would really appreciate the help if anybody knows.

Comment: On any *nix host, simply open a terminal and enter `ssh-keygen` - boom, you have a key at `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and your public key at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, the `.pub` file needs to go into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target machine. Also, voting to close as off topic as this is not about programming.

Comment: @Matt Clark So in the authorized_keys directory I'm supposed to paste the .pub file or the long key that's within that file? Someone else suggested pasting the key in that directory but then you're saying to paste the filename. Also why would my question be off-topic? I don't get how this doesn't deal with programming?

Comment: _authorized_keys_ is a file. Dump the contents of the .pub file into the authorized keys file, any key in that file will be allowed to auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

To remove the host from known_hosts.

Then, you can add your macbook key when you create the droplet from the DigitalOcean panel. If the droplet is already created, you can copy your macbook key from your terminal to the clipboard with

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then SSH into the droplet and edit the file authorized_keys

```
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and paste your key. ctrl+x and 'y' to exit and save the file.

Now you should be able to SSH into your droplet without entering the password anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but I'm still confused. I copied the public key from the pub file and pasted it into the authorized_keys directory. Was I also supposed to include the words `ssh-rsa` with the whole alpha-numeric key in there? Thanks for the reply, I'm still stuck on one part but I think you resolved my answer

Comment: authorized_keys is a file, not a directory. You should edit it and paste the content of the id_rsa.pub file from your mac.